# How does Swindler interact with Spoils (or other cards not in supply)?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue, dominion-dark-ages

The Swindler card says:

> Each other player trashes top card of his deck and gains a card with the same cost that you choose.

We've encountered a situation when Swindler stumbled upon Spoils card, which is not in the supply, and hence does not have a cost defined. What is to be done then? The owner of the Swindler would of course be happy to give Ruins to the affected player instead, but I am not quite sure what the right way to resolve this is.

[image: Swindler (from Intrigue): +2 dollars. Each other player trashes the top card of his deck and gains a card with the same cost that you choose. (This card is action/attack, and costs 3.)] [image: Spoils (from Dark Ages): 3 dollars. When you play this, return it to the Spoils pile. (This is not in the Supply.) (This card is a treasure, and costs 0.)]

Comment: If he would happily give a ruins, he should be much more happy to give a curse. Note that curse is available every game, even if there is no curse-giver available.

Comment: Note that the Swindler *is* a "curse-giver"...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cost of Spoils is 0. When you 'gain(s)' a card, unless it specifically names a card not in the supply, you can only choose for cards from the supply.

Copper, Curse, and Ruins (when playing with them) are in the supply and cost 0. Making all valid choices for cards that can be gained when Swindler trashes Spoils.

http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Cost

> Every card in Dominion has a cost indicated in its lower left corner.
>
> A few costs are listed with asterisks: *0** is used on
>   several cards that can be gained from outside the Supply; the asterisk
>   serves to remind players that they cannot actually be bought for
>   *0*